# How to add the number of line at the end of line in linux

Tags: linux

How to add the number of line at the end of the corresponding line into a file text in linux ?

I know this command, but it add the number of line at the beginning and not at the end !

```
nl -ba -s ', ' fileName.txt > fileName2.txt
```

e.g.

```
5,10,33  
7,17,77
```

have to be

```
5,10,33,1
7,17,77,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in awk:

```
awk '{print $0","NR;}' file
```

on my system:

```
$ cat file
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
$ awk '{print $0","NR;}' file
1 2,1
3 4,2
5 6,3
7 8,4
```

Comment: I have a problem, some time the character ^M is inserted ?!

Comment: @MohammedGh you must have the file edited in Windows. that's `\r`. you need to change your new line to unix format first.